# Converting Vectors into a Data Frame for ANOVA

Tags: r

I want to run a two-way ANOVA on my data. I have two factors (call them A and B), and then 2 levels within each factor (call them A.1 and A.2, and B.1 and B.2, respectively). I have 4 vectors of numerical data, one corresponding to each of A.1, A.2, B.1, and B.2. What is the fastest way to get these vectors into a data frame so that I can run a two-way ANOVA? Is there some function in plyr to help me do this? Thank you.

Comment: Without seeing some sample data, it is difficult to provide meaningful guidance. Easiest was is to cbind the vectors together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created the data frame from scratch, you should fill the vectors with your data. 
To run the ANOVA you need to have the factors and levels indicated in different columns in your dataframe, here they will be named 'fac' and 'lev'.

```
va1 <- c(  1,  2,  3,  4)
va2 <- c( -4, -3, -2, -1)
vb1 <- c(  9, 10, 11, 12)
vb2 <- c( -9,-10,-11,-12)

fac <- c(rep("A", 8), rep("B", 8))
lev <- c(rep("1", 4), rep("2", 4), rep("1", 4), rep("2", 4))
val <- c(va1, va2, vb1, vb2)

df     <- as.data.frame(cbind(fac,lev,val))
df$val <- as.numeric(df$val)

anova(lm(val ~ fac * lev, df))
```

Comment: I guess this works, though it's not exactly sleek. It's more or less what I did.